# About Hardy-Littlewood maximal function from Grafakos' "Classical Fourier Analysis"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator $M$ is defined by
$$
M f(x)=\sup_{r>0}|B(x,r)|^{-1}\int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|dy.
$$

There is the following example in Grafakos's "Classical Fourier Analysis" book about this function.
$$M \chi_{_{[a,b]}}(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{b-a}{2|x-b|} & x\leq a \\
       1 & a< x< b \\
      \frac{b-a}{2|x-a|} &  x\geq b \\
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

It was written "it is clear" for the case "$M \chi_{_{[a,b]}}(x)=1$ when $x\in (a,b)$". Unfortunately i can't understand this fact. Can anyone write the proof of this fact more explicitly?

My other question: is that fact is true also for n-dimension, i.e., $M \chi_{_{B(z,t)}}(x)= 1$, when $x\in B(z,t)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just recall that we have 
$$
\dfrac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|dy \leq \sup_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|\dfrac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} dy = \sup_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|\leq \sup_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(y)|.
$$

This holds for every $r>0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that $M f(x)\leq \sup_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(y)|$. Taking $f=\chi_{B(z,s)}$ gives that the maximal function applied to this $f$ is bounded above by 1. On the other hand if you pick $x\in B(z,s)$ and $0<r<s-|x-z|$, then 
$$
1= \dfrac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} \chi_{B(z,s)}(y)dy\leq M \chi_{B(z,s)}(x).
$$
Combining this implies that $M \chi_{B(z,s)}(x)=1$ for every $x\in B(z,s)$.